# How to sort by column that is type of string but alphabet is not relevant in sorting?

Tags: mysql, sql

I need to sort for each person_id column, where order priorities are:

1. actual: 1 > 0
2. type: Reg > Zee = Con
3. date_start: DESC

So, from data:

```
+----+-----------+------+------------+------------+--------+
| id | person_id | type | date_start | date_end   | actual |
+----+-----------+------+------------+------------+--------+
| 1  | 1         | Reg  | 01-01-2018 | 31-01-2018 | 0      |
+----+-----------+------+------------+------------+--------+
| 2  | 1         | Con  | 01-02-2019 | 01-05-2019 | 0      |
+----+-----------+------+------------+------------+--------+
| 3  | 2         | Reg  | 01-01-2018 | 31-05-2018 | 0      |
+----+-----------+------+------------+------------+--------+
| 4  | 2         | Reg  | 01-05-2018 | 31-07-2019 | 1      |
+----+-----------+------+------------+------------+--------+
| 5  | 2         | Con  | 01-06-2018 | 31-04-2020 | 1      |
+----+-----------+------+------------+------------+--------+
| 6  | 2         | Zee  | 31-05-2019 | 31-08-2019 | 1      |
+----+-----------+------+------------+------------+--------+
```

I need query that for person_id = 1, result in:

```
    +----+-----------+------+------------+------------+--------+
    | id | person_id | type | date_start | date_end   | actual |
    +----+-----------+------+------------+------------+--------+
    | 1  | 1         | Reg  | 01-01-2018 | 31-01-2018 | 0      |
    +----+-----------+------+------------+------------+--------+
    | 2  | 1         | Con  | 01-02-2019 | 01-05-2019 | 0      |
    +----+-----------+------+------------+------------+--------+
```

And for person_id = 2, result in:

```
+----+-----------+------+------------+------------+--------+
| id | person_id | type | date_start | date_end   | actual |
+----+-----------+------+------------+------------+--------+
| 4  | 2         | Reg  | 01-05-2018 | 31-07-2019 | 1      |
+----+-----------+------+------------+------------+--------+
| 6  | 2         | Zee  | 31-05-2019 | 31-08-2019 | 1      |
+----+-----------+------+------------+------------+--------+
| 5  | 2         | Con  | 01-06-2018 | 31-04-2020 | 1      |
+----+-----------+------+------------+------------+--------+
| 3  | 2         | Reg  | 01-01-2018 | 31-05-2018 | 0      |
+----+-----------+------+------------+------------+--------+
```

(Also, but this is additional question, I need to take oldest start_date from query but ONLY if date continuity was maintained between each rows)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use `CASE` expression to add specific weights:

```
ORDER BY actual DESC, CASE WHEN `type` = 'Reg' THEN 1 ELSE 2 END, date_start DESC
```

Comment: Great, I will accept that answer, but what about addictional question form bootom of post?

Comment: @Sruj `I need to take oldest start_date from query but ONLY if date continuity was maintained between each rows` Could you prepare https://dbfiddle.uk with sample demo? I am not sure if I get  date continuity correctly

Comment: Date continuity is when dates from start to end is constantly ... damn this isn't so simple, forget about it. Its impossible to be done.